# Como obtener el valor de un drop down list en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola tengo cargado el ddl en esta consulta :

```
public void loadItems(DropDownList ddl, string id_catalogo)
    {
        ItemBL oItem = new ItemBL();
        ddl.DataSource = oItem.ListarItem(id_catalogo);
        ddl.DataTextField = "descripcion";
        ddl.DataValueField = "id_tabla";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- TODOS --", ""));
        ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Quiero obtener el valor del DDL este es mi codigo:

```
CartasGarantiasBL obj = new CartasGarantiasBL();
        List<CartasGarantiasEL> lst = obj.ListarCG(DateTime.Parse(txtfech1.Text), DateTime.Parse(txtfech2.Text),ddlCliente.SelectedItem.Text);
        gvMarcas.DataSource = lst;
        gvMarcas.DataBind();
```

quiero obtener el valor de ese combo por favor ayudenme

Answer (score 1):

El `DropDownList` tiene la propiedad [SelectedValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.5#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_SelectedValue) que podrias usar para obtener el valor seleccionado

En este caso recuperaria el dato relacionado con `id_tabla`

Recomendaria separar un poco los datos para poder inspeccionarlos

```
int clienteId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCliente.SelectedValue);

List<CartasGarantiasEL> lst = obj.ListarCG(DateTime.Parse(txtfech1.Text), 
                                            DateTime.Parse(txtfech2.Text), 
                                            clienteId);
```

Imagine que al ser un `id` el valor seria numerico por eso la conversion, sino es asi puede quitarla.

Por otro lado recuerda que si estas perdiendo la seleccion y siempre obtienes el mismo valor puede deberse a que estas cargando la lista de combo en el evento `Load` del form sin evaluar si es postback

```
public void Page_Load(...){

     if(!IsPostBack){
       loadItems(...);
     } 
}
```

es importnte que este dentro de ese if, sino en un evento perderas la seleccion